# how to Insert multiple rows using PQputCopyData

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am trying to insert multiple row from char buffer using PQputcoydata function of libpq in postgreSQL.
But not sure how to give the newline character . I tried something like this

const char *buffer1 = "32183,3,1,0,,1234,418,Kirti GEN,0,34543,1234,0,2013-09-03 14:39:56.000,2013-09-03 14:39:56.000,0,0,0.0000,1,0,0,\n,32183,3,1,0,,1234,418,John Doe,0,34543,1234,0,2013-09-03 14:39:56.000,2013-09-03 14:39:56.000,0,0,0.0000,1,0,0";

I am getting error  "extra data after last expected column" after first \n

What is the right way to give newline when we do copy from  STDIN in postgre library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put a comma before or after the \n.

The error message means either you have too many fields in your data, or too few fields in the table or field-list which you are inserting into.

The comma before the \n means that the first row is interpreted to end with an empty field (either the empty string, or NULL, depending on how you invoke the COPY), which is possibly what you want but I doubt it (especially considering the error message).

The comma after the \n means the second row is interpreted to start with an empty field, which is surely not what you want.